# Как подключить PHPUnit к проекту на openServer?

Tags: php, openserver, phpunit

Пытаюсь сделать unit тестирование при помощи UnitTest. Скачал файл *phpunit-6.5.6.phar* и не могу разобраться что мне с ним делать? Куда его скопировать? Как использовать с openServer? Во всех статьях авторы говорили, мол, прописываем эту команду в консоль:

```
@php "%~dp0phpunit-5.7.17.phar" %*
```

В какую консоль? Что авторы имеют в виду? В одном видео автор вообще скачивал библиотеку Pear в то время как другие обходились без нее.

Итого:
Как мне сделать нормальное тестирование на PHPUnit, используя OpenServer. Как подключить этот фреймворк к проекту?

Comment: Для запуска вам нужно скачать PHAR файл, открыть консоль PHP в OpenServer, и запускать оттуда php Phpunit.phar , не забудьте указать путь до этого файла ну и остальные параметры для трестируемого файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.phar.php

> Модуль phar предоставляет возможность поместить целое PHP-приложение в
>   один единственный файл, именуемый phar (PHP Archive), для его более
>   простого распространения и установки.

Вся задача для запуска такого типа файлов сводиться к правильному пути PHP на вашем сервере.

В случае OpenServer нажимаете правой кнопкой на иконке, выбираете "Дополнительно" -> "Консоль". Далее переходите в место где у вас находиться искомый файл и пишете `php phpunit-6.5.6.phar` с нужным вам синтаксисом.

Я проверил у себя, на скрине видно начало вывода `phpinfo()`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!